# Add to HTML input array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input field like this in jade:

```
input(name='saintForm[quotes][]', type='hidden')
```

I want to use jquery to add to this array from a dynamic unordered list, but not sure how.  Here's my failing attempt:

```
  $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.quote').each(function (i){
      var item = $(this).text().replace(' (x)','');
      $("input[name='saintForm[quotes][]']").push(item);
    });
    this.submit();
  });
```

Comment: You don't have an array, you have an array-like jQuery object, and it has no `push` method. You're probably looking for jQuery's `add()` method, but without knowing what `item` is, that's impossible to know ?

Comment: Sorry, addded the item.  I tried using add(), but the results on the server still show up blank -- quotes: [ '' ]

Comment: As @adeneo mentioned, you do not have an array. I think the only way to do this is to iterate over the quotes and add to the input value individually.

Comment: I see your edit, but now you're trying to add a string to a jQuery collection. Maybe you're just looking for jQuery's map to return an array of the modified strings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just adding a value to the default form functionality you could create an input with a value.

```
 // grab your form and wrap it in jQuery
 var myForm = $('#form'); 

 // list teo the submit event
 myForm.on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $('li.quote').each(function() {
       $('<input />', { 
           type: 'text', // input type
           name: 'saintForm[quotes][]', // the name of the form input
           value: $(this).text() // the text from the current list-item
       }).appendTo(myForm); // append each input to the form     

   });

   myForm.submit(); // submit the form

});
```

You can of course send all sorts of arbitrary data to the server easily with AJAX but if you are just using the normal form submit I guess this is a good way to do it.

Comment: This works with some minor edits.  First I was able to get rid of the hidden element since they are being created dynamically, and second I changed the type from 'text' to 'hidden'.  Thank you.